# SDTT warns that "geo" and "hasMap" are "not recognized by Google for an object of type DiagnosticLab"

Tags: schema.org

I'm getting these warnings in Google's SDTT when I test my JSON-LD:

[image]

Is it just because of the type `DiagnosticLab`? Should I remove that part of the code?

Comment: Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The [`geo`](http://schema.org/geo) and [`hasMap`](http://schema.org/hasMap) properties are not defined for the [`DiagnosticLab`](http://health-lifesci.schema.org/DiagnosticLab) type. They can only be used for `Place` and its sub-types.

The [`location`](http://schema.org/location) property allows you to provide where "an organization is located" (you can provide a `Place` value). The [`contactPoint`](http://schema.org/contactPoint) and [`address`](http://schema.org/address) properties might also be of interest.